# Watch for Changes with MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()

Tags: javascript

I currently have a method for continuously polling `MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`, which returns an array of connected media devices.

```
let devices = [];

function getDevices() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
            resolve(devices);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}

async function listenForDeviceChanges() {
    devices = await getDevices();
    setTimeout(listenForDeviceChanges, 500);
}


(async () => {
    await listenForDeviceChanges();
})();
```

This seems inefficient, so I wonder if there is another method to do this in the MediaDevices API? Specifically some sort of "watcher" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the `devicechange` event:

> This happens whenever the set of media devices available to the user agent and, by extension, to the web site or app has changed
>
> — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange

E.g.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange = async function(event) {
  devices = await getDevices();
};
```